# yesod Persistent query, how to distinct a Field

Tags: sql, yesod, persistent

Simplify,What I want to achive in yesod Persistent Query is liken

SQL:selelct distinct(name) form table;

Answer (score 0):

You can use esqueleto to perform those kinds of queries.